# Setting colour of beamer itemize bullet depending on alert mode

Tags: beamer, lists, color, itemize

I know how to globally set the colour of beamer's itemize bullets. I've defined my own symbols for them and I'd like to colour them in `\alert` mode. (At the moment only the colour of the text changes, but not the colour of the bullets.)

At the moment I'm using the following definition for the "bullets":

```
\setbeamertemplate{itemize        item}{\CorkSquare[size=0.18,linewidth=0.70pt]}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize     subitem}{\CorkSquare[size=0.16,linewidth=0.67pt]}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize  subsubitem}{\CorkSquare[size=0.14,linewidth=0.65pt]}
\def\CorkSquare[size=#1,linewidth=#2]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[use as bounding box]
         (+0.75*#1,-0.15*#1)
         (+0.80*#1,+0.75*#1)
         (+0.75*#1,-0.15*#1);
    \filldraw[line width=#2,draw=cork@colour@normal,fill=cork@colour@normal!19!white]
             (0,0) rectangle (#1,#1);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This assumes you can use an action specification (that is, you want to highlight the entire `\item` and not just a part of it). Normally the action specification works like `\item<1-|alert@1> text` which will show the item from slide 1 onwards and highlights it only on slide 1. What we can do is define our own version of alert to change the `itemize item` for that specific item and then perform the normal `alert` as well. This is done by creating a new environment `<actionname>env`. So to get a `myalert` action we define the `myalertenv` environment. We can do this as follows:

```
\newenvironment{myalertenv}{\only{\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\def\mycolor{red}\CorkSquare[size=0.18,linewidth=0.70pt]}}\alertenv}{\endalertenv}
```

Since I don't know the definition of your `cork@colour@normal` I change the code a bit to use the `\mycolor` command. You can just modify it to use what you want. The full code would look like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \setbeamertemplate{itemize        item}{\CorkSquare[size=0.18,linewidth=0.70pt]}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize     subitem}{\CorkSquare[size=0.16,linewidth=0.67pt]}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize  subsubitem}{\CorkSquare[size=0.14,linewidth=0.65pt]}
\def\mycolor{blue}
\def\CorkSquare[size=#1,linewidth=#2]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[use as bounding box]
         (+0.75*#1,-0.15*#1)
         (+0.80*#1,+0.75*#1)
         (+0.75*#1,-0.15*#1);
    \filldraw[line width=#2,draw=\mycolor,fill=\mycolor!19!white]
             (0,0) rectangle (#1,#1);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newenvironment{myalertenv}{\only{\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\def\mycolor{red}\CorkSquare[size=0.18,linewidth=0.70pt]}}\alertenv}{\endalertenv}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item<1-> test
    \item<2-|myalert@2> test
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** By the way, you should realyl consider changing your `\CorkSquare` command to just `\def\CorkSquare[#1,#2]`. Then you can use `#1` as the size and put `#2` in the options to `\filldraw`. right now you can also just put `, other options` behind the `linewidth=...` but that looks a bit strange when you call it and it would require you to change the order because otherwise draw and fillcolor would be overwritten. This way you would not need the `\mycolor` construct. Your code would then become the following, which I believe to be a bit cleaner.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
  \setbeamertemplate{itemize        item}{\CorkSquare[size=0.18,line width=0.70pt]}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize     subitem}{\CorkSquare[size=0.16,line width=0.67pt]}
\setbeamertemplate{itemize  subsubitem}{\CorkSquare[size=0.14,line width=0.65pt]}
\def\CorkSquare[size=#1,#2]{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}
    \draw[use as bounding box]
         (+0.75*#1,-0.15*#1)
         (+0.80*#1,+0.75*#1)
         (+0.75*#1,-0.15*#1);
    \filldraw[draw=blue,fill=blue!19!white,#2]
             (0,0) rectangle (#1,#1);
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}
\newenvironment{myalertenv}{\only{\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\CorkSquare[size=0.18,line width=0.70pt,draw=red,fill=red!19!white]}}\alertenv}{\endalertenv}
\begin{frame}
  \begin{itemize}
    \item<1-> test
    \item<2-|myalert@2> test
  \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Edit:** After your comment that there was an issue when multiple frames have an alert specification I looked into it. This is in fact the case. It is caused because normally the frame specification created by the action are put on the `\only`. Actually they are placed after the expansion of the begin of the environment, and so the `\only` should be last. Right now the `\alertenv` is last and therefore the frame specification is passed to the `alert` and not to the `\only`. We can't put the `\alertenv` in the `\only`, because at the end of the environment there is no frame specification and therefore `\endalertenv` won't be in the only and thus show up in every frame, causiing problems. What we need to do is place some extra code in the `\only` such that the command at the end is only defined to be `\endalertenv` when the `\only` is executed and otherwise is equal to `\relax`. You can use the following as the environment definition:

```
\newenvironment{myalertenv}{\let\neweae\relax\only{\setbeamertemplate{itemize item}{\CorkSquare[size=0.18,line width=0.70pt,draw=red,fill=red!19!white]}\alertenv\let\neweae\endalertenv}}{\neweae}
```

This will only place the modified item label and the alert on frames specified by the frame specification.

Comment: Thanks. It's a nice idea but I'd prefer to stick to the standard `alert` notation. I scanned the manual but I couldn't find any `beamertemplate` that let me do what I want. do you know if there's a macro of the form `\ifalertmode{<true part>}{<false part>}` that expands to `<true part>` if `beamer` is in alert mode and to `<flase part>` otherwise?

Comment: you could modify the `\alert` command (and if you use the action the `alertenv` environment) to set a flag. You might have to look into expansion control inside of the alert command then...

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: By the way, is it your intention to use `\item<1-> \alert{text}` or do you want to use the action specification. Because when using the `\alert` method, I doubt that you are already in "alert mode" as you call it, when the item is created, so that wouldn't work.

Comment: I want to use `\item<spec>`. I can see that `\alert{<text>}` won't get me anywhere. I'd prefer it if I didn't have to change the `\alert` method because then things may break if I update my `beamer` installation. I'm surprised there isn't a standard way to colour the "bullets".

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: The really strange thing is that the cover of the `beamer` manual seems to suggest that this is the default behaviour. If your only objection to my method is that you have to use `myalert` instead of `alert` then you can ofcourse just renew the `alertenv` environment and perform the same task. If you have other objections, could you make them more clear, because in that case I don't really understand the syntax you would like to use and what contraints you have on possible solutions.

Comment: I just noticed this solution has a similar problem because it turns all bullets to red if all items have environments `alertenv@x`. For example `\item<alertenv@1>` and `\item<alertenv@2>`. This really deosn't help at all:-(

Comment: @MarcvanDongen: You are right... I updated the answer, should be fixed now.